# Program for constantly recording audio of the past 24 hours

Tags: audio, recording

I want a program to continuously record the audio of my microphone for the past 24 hours (like a surveillance system) so I can have the audio of the past 24 hours.

Is there a progeny for doing this?

If not, how should I do that?

Comment: do you mean a program that only records audio when a certain threshold is reached? So you would not have to get an audio file 24 hours long, but an audio file which contains only the audio that reached the threshold?

Comment: @nath no, I want full recording of the past 24 hours.

Comment: do you really mean the "past 24" hours? The audio has to be saved somehow, somewhere... Why should a normal recording tool not being capable of recording 24 hours if you have enough disk space?